# can simply beating cast material with a hammer inside a mold improve it's strength

Tags: material-science, casting, forging

I asked my material-science professor if forging a cast part (inside a mold to prevent shape change) can increase its strength to that of a forged part.
She told me to find out myself and tell the group the next lesson. I googled for a bit on post-casting treatment but haven't got a clear answer to my question. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Generally , no. That is more or less cold working , but the die prevents much strain , so very limited strain hardening / cold work. That could be called a "coining" operation. A special case could be a poor casting with gas porosity , shrinkage cracks or hot tears ; wherein the forging partially remedies some of these defects.

Comment: what if the cast was above recrystalization temperature?

Comment: As it recrystallizes it removes residual stress and cold work ; depending on specifics ,it anneals and lower strength..